# Custom drag calendar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I wanted to know how I could implement a custom calendar that looks like this: https://dribbble.com/shots/843863-Date-Filter/attachments/88756 in iOS. The user would be able to drag the dates in order to selected or deselect them. I'm a still a bit new to iOS development so I need some pointers on where to start looking for possible solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view controller, get the location of the touch in `touchesBegan`, and figure out the day from that touch. Then do the same thing in `touchesEnded`. Use the two dates as the boundaries of the date range, and voilà, that's it. If you want to animate the date range as the user drags their finger, then do the same thing in `touchesMoved` as well.

For the blue bar showing the date range, you could use blue left and right half-circle images for the ends of the rows, a blue rectangle for the middle of the row, and change all the buttons in the date range (except the boundary dates) to have no background image or foreground image, and turn the text color white. The boundary date views just get new background images.

In general, if you have anything that is in a grid, then you can figure out screen coordinates to grid coordinates (or vice versa) easily with a bit of math. Also, if there are some fancy graphics you want to make, break the whole thing into smaller parts that go with the views currently on the screen, and use your current views as "anchors" for where to put new views.